# what does to begin with mean?

Tags: vocabulary

But to follow this will it is necessary to know it, and above all to distinguish it from the particular will, beginning with one's self.

**my problem is that I can not understand what BEGINNING WITH means here.**
 Would you please tell me, if am I correctly explain  this part of sentence BEGINNING WITH 
 SOMETHING?

To begin with some thing, in this sentence, means at the start of a process, event, or situation

And, what about this sentence? has  that part(begin with something) the same meaning with the following?

The recommendation from all authorities is to begin with diet.

Comment: Just for fun: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XGpEDUVCRb8

Answer (score 2):

Study these sentences -

> You should educate everybody, *beginning with yourself* - First you start educating yourself and then spread it to everyone around.

And,

> The teachers wanted to educate everyone in the village. But they said it should *begin with the village-head.*

In both sentences, *begin* mean -to start. In former, it's used in *progressive form* and in the latter it's *simple form*.

See various verb forms [here](http://leo.stcloudstate.edu/grammar/tenses.html).